# Can't add file to list, async method

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await

I have, what I would have thought, a simple problem.

```
 Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    File a = File(pickedFile.path);
    setState(() {
      _imageList[0] = a;
      _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
    print(_image.toString());
    print(_imageList[0].toString());
  }
```

Anytime I do this (or any other variant of it -- I've tried loads), I get the following error:

```
E/flutter ( 6595): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]=' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 6595): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 6595): Tried calling: []=(0, Instance of '_File')
```

I can print the _image. And I can display it, so there's nothing wrong with it. The only thing is that I can't, for some reason, add files to my list.

Comment: Initialize the `_imageList`: `_imageList = new List(numOfImages)`.

Comment: Thanks. Silly me.